# TFrecords parsed then pass to tf.keras.Sequential?How?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

Below is the code I used the route should be:imgs_inputfn()>NNTrainEvalBuild(), What I know is that I take TFRecords,

Parse it as in decode it.

Out(image&label),

Then do some processing on the images(not sure important or not).

Then again turn it into a tensor, and the tensor is just a dict with a label.

1)With tensor how can I make it into an input for (NNTrainEvalBuild), NNTainEvalBuild is just a Brain* in my mindset. But it seems like the brain doesn't have input.

2)If NNTrainEvalBuild, is really just a brain* and all I have done is just define the NeuralNetwork/Brain
then how do I train it with the tensors/parsed TFrecords.

Should I do a manual loop to train or tf already have a module of calling a function with an argument?
E.g.:Handsome.py, have a function: TrainBrain(tensor): find the brain, take the brain train with tensor

then all I need to do is

import tf.Handsome as OMG

OMG.TrainBrain(tensor)

but even with this how the function take my (Brain/NeuralNetwork)?

3,visualise)It's something like I had a brain(NN) and a world with pictures(TFRecords).

But it seems like the reflected light is infra red so I process it to visible light(tensor)

But somehow The brain doesn't come with a eye(Some function that take tensor and N.N. link them together.)

??Any help would be great, as I had gone around searching for tutorials that have high-level API support.

Win-10,TF-1.15,Use Virtual Env for ML,

```
import TensorFlow

def imgs_input_fn(tfRecordspath, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1, batch_size=1):
    def parse_function(serialized):
        features = \
        {
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
        parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized,features)
        Image_ypix=720
        Image_xpix=480
        Input_name="kakoii"
        # Get the image as raw bytes.
        image_shape = tf.stack([Image_ypix,Image_xpix, 3])
        image_raw = parsed_example['image']
        label = tf.cast(parsed_example['label'], tf.float32)
        # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
        image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
        #image = tf.subtract(image, pixel_val?) # Zero-center by mean pixel,too complex 
        image = tf.reverse(image, axis=[2]) # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        tensor = dict(zip([input_name], [image])), [label]
        return tensor
    tfRecordspath=input("TFRecords's path:")
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfRecordspath)
    # Parse the serialized data in the TFRecords files.
    # This returns TensorFlow tensors for the image and labels.
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 256 elements (read into memory)
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=256)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat_count)  # Repeats dataset this # times
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  # Batch size to use
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
    return batch_features, batch_labels

def oldTrainorEval():
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(path_tfrecords_train,
                                                                   perform_shuffle=True,
                                                                   repeat_count=5,
                                                                   batch_size=20), 
                                    max_steps=500)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(path_tfrecords_test,
                                                                 perform_shuffle=False,
                                                                 batch_size=1))
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(est_catvsdog, train_spec, eval_spec)

def NNTrainEvalBuild():

    model=tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(720,480)),
    #tf.keras.layers.Flatten(10,inputshape=(image_ypixel,image_xpixel)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])          
    #tf.keras.layer.dense(unit=4,)      ,concept4 unit ,out8 ,using upper as trial
```

Comment: batchfeatures: {'kakoii  ': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:0' shape=(?, 720, 480, 3) dtype=float32>}

batchlabels: Tensor("IteratorGetNext_1:1", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

Comment: Please correct me if my procedure or any concept is wrong. As I am new to ML and tf